# 301 Redirect only non-filesystem requests to new domain

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, redirect, filesystems, 301-redirect

I want to use .htaccess on an Apache server to redirect only calls to the server that are not files or folders in the filesystem. For example, if the server gets a request for:

`http://www.domain.tld/page1.html`

And page1.html is not an actual file on the server, it should 301 redirect to:

`http://new.domain.tld/page1.html`

Otherwise, it should not do anything. Is this possible? If so, how? Please provide some example code if possible. The code I currently have is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.tld [NC]
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://subdomain.newdomain.tld/$1 [L,R=301]
```

While this does the redirect, it doesn't ignore actual files and folders on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the tested solution:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.tld [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.tld [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://subdomain.newdomain.tld/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Lines 3 & 4 tell apache to apply the rule when the request comes with a www or not, without regard to capital or lower-case letters. The `!-f` and `!-d` at the ends of lines 5 & 6 respectively tell apache to avoid applying the redirect to existing files and directories.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using Apache's `mod_rewrite`, which allows you to redirect requests using the `RewriteRule` directive.  You can make this conditional on a file existing using the `RewriteCond` directive.  The [mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) is probably a good place to start.

Comment: Read the section on special RewriteCond patterns, such as `-f` and `-d`.  If you show me how you've tried using these and what sort of behavior you encountered, I'll provide some suggestions on how to fix it.